# Find all File IO operations in C# code (maybe through static analysis)

Tags: c#, code-analysis

Are there any ways to find all code that invokes IO operations like `File.WriteAllText`, `Request.Files["filename"].SaveAs("out")`, etc?

For now I can just grep for all possible common ways to read/write files with something like that for example:

```
grep 'SaveAs' -I -r . -l | grep "\.cs"
```

This is not satisfactory because I can't think of all possible ways files can be read and written. Maybe it could be done via reflection somehow or through analysis of system calls in compiled binaries? Any ideas?

EDIT:
If method A calls method B and method B calls method C, and method C does a file operation it would be good to have that code identified as well. However, just to simplify the problem finding direct calls to IO would be sufficient.

Comment: @Rawling right, deleted my comment.

Comment: If method A calls method B and method B calls method C, and method C does a file operation, do you need A in this list?

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to develop this tool, you can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163641.aspx).

The article describes ways to detect assembly and method dependencies, so you could find all methods that calls IO primitives, such as `FileStream.Write`.

Answer (score 1):

So on a whim I decided to try this using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/).

It's pretty simple to recursively get a list of all the methods that a method calls:

```
static IEnumerable<MethodDefinition> GetMethodsCalledInMethod(MethodDefinition md)
{
    if (md.Body == null)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<MethodDefinition>();
    }

    return md.Body.Instructions
        .Select(i => i.Operand)
        .OfType<MethodReference>()
        .Select(mr => mr.Resolve())
        .Where(mr => mr != null);
}
```

You can get all the methods in an assembly you want to inspect:

```
var ad = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(typeof(ATypeInTheAssembly).Assembly.Location);
var allMethodsInAssembly = ad.Modules
    .SelectMany(m => m.Types)
    .SelectMany(t => t.Methods));
```

You can then recurse through this tree of method calls until you find a method call which looks like an IO call.

```
Func<MethodDefinition, bool> isFileOperation = md =>
    md.DeclaringType.Name == "FileStream";
```

Is this sufficient? I don't know. `File.WriteAllText` uses a `FileStream`. The `SaveAs` example you gave does too. But does *every* file access go through a `FileStream`? I can't say.

This approach also has issues:

- You need to look out for recursive calls, because otherwise your recursion will turn into an infinite loop and you'll blow your stack.
- This is *sloooow*. When I analysed a simple console application that called `File.WriteAllLines` I got a result immediately, but when I tried to analyse the analyser itself it got lost in the tree.
- If you run into an interface - or even a virtual method - you can't know for sure what the implementation is going to be, so you can't know whether it'll perform an IO operation or not!

Comment: That's a very good point regarding interfaces. I suppose the problem has to be solved in terms of available runtime environment (DLLs/implementations).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much do you want to do in depth analysis.
If you're really serious about catching all 'System.IO' method calls I would suggest using [NRefactory](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory/). It's a front-end C# parser which can parse C# code and generated syntax tree and code resolver.
There's good tutorial about using it in [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408663/Using-NRefactory-for-analyzing-Csharp-code) that can help you to get started. Also in code project tutorial sample there's auxiliary classes that let you to load the whole solution, and provide you with code resolver.
If you need more sample you can find some in my [blog](https://arashtaher.wordpress.com/tag/nrefactory/).

PS : I'll try to extend this answer with code sample in a few hours.